# Disappeared question

Tags: support

I hope this is the place to ask such things.

Yesterday I posted a Q&A about a new chrome extension that I wrote to improve learning.
I don't find it anywhere even in my profile, maybe it has been moved (to here) or removed without any notice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was closed as off-topic by several users with the following reason:

> "Questions seeking **resources or advice** about learning Japanese are off-topic here, but you may find our list of resources for learning Japanese helpful." – istrasci, naruto, Flaw

We try to keep our site focused on questions about the language itself, not about learning methods or programs to help with learning.

Since the question was clearly off-topic and had no chance of being reopened, I removed it rather than leave it "on hold".  To be honest, it read more like an advertisement for your Chrome extension than a real question; it wasn't really written in a way that invited answers from other users.

The link to your question can be found below, although not everyone will be able to see it:

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53771/how-to-create-faster-anki-card

If you'd like to share your Chrome extension with other users on the site, feel free to stop by chat and post a link to your extension there.

Comment: OP can also add information about such an extension to their profile.

Comment: Well, opened it as Q&A for people to use it, as a free resource to use. I understood that  I can do it from this page https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Anyway, I accept that it's against the site rules. But I didn't get any notification about it so I had no chance to figure it out.